# How to use iPad as presenter for MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, projector, slideshow

If I have a MacBook connected to a projector, how do I use my iPad as the presenter for slide switching?

There are solutions for using Keynote [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24165?viewlocale=en_US&locale=no_NO)

But how do I do it just with PDF slides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking about remotely controlling your iPad which is plugged in to a monitor.

The simplest solution in my opinion would be a bluetooth keyboard.

If you're trying to remote control your Macbook from the iPad you could use Astropad, teamviewer or similar application.

Comment: Thanks, but there's a bit misunderstanding. I want to use Ipad to control MacBook which is connected to a projector. Especially, I just want to control the slide for presentation

Comment: What's the issue with using Astropad or TeamViewer apps to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier just to get a [presentation remote device](https://www.amazon.com/Office-Presentation-Remotes/b?ie=UTF8&node=160358011) and forego the iPad. Exactly what utility does the iPad provide in this situation that an inexpensive device can't?

Comment: It's just urgent... Presentation will happend tomorrow, while I don't have presenter in hand...

Comment: That's too bad. There's no app, other than Keynote Remote, that can provide this kind of service. **Staples**, or any other large office store, will have these presentation remotes in stock. You _can_ build a Keynote presentation with the PDF files. Depending on the number of PDF files, it may not take too long.